# Database creation error: Access Denied Odoo 14

Tags: postgresql, odoo, odoo-14

I have searched a lot of sources without any success. I installed odoo 14 in my system, and now trying to create the first db and it is giving Database Creation Error.

[image]

My odoo-server.conf:

```
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
admin_passwd = admin
db_host = False
db_port = False
db_user = odoo
db_password = False
logfile = /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log
addons_path = /opt/odoo/src/addons,/opt/odoo/src/odoo/addons
```

List of databases present in psql:

```
 List of databases
      Name      |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate | Ctype |   Access privileges   
----------------+----------+----------+---------+-------+-----------------------
 UNEXT-COE21    | postgres | UTF8     | en_IN   | en_IN | 
 engro          | postgres | UTF8     | en_IN   | en_IN | 
 myproject      | postgres | UTF8     | en_IN   | en_IN | 
 postgres       | postgres | UTF8     | en_IN   | en_IN | 
 template0      | postgres | UTF8     | en_IN   | en_IN | =c/postgres          +
                |          |          |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1      | postgres | UTF8     | en_IN   | en_IN | =c/postgres          +
                |          |          |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
 testdb         | postgres | UTF8     | en_IN   | en_IN | =Tc/postgres         +
                |          |          |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres+
                |          |          |         |       | arijit=CTc/postgres
 unextcoeserver | postgres | UTF8     | en_IN   | en_IN |
```

PSQL users present:

```
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 arijit    | Create DB                                                  | {}
 odoo      | Create DB                                                  | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

I tried these: [Link](https://bobcares.com/blog/database-creation-error-access-denied-odoo/) and [Link](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/database-creation-error-access-denied-105200)

No solution yet.

Comment: Try creating database from back end.

Comment: @Saks_here: Yeah database is present and working.

Comment: How do you run your Odoo process?

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem solved. By modifying the Odoo.config file and running the same using CLI.

Those who are facing similar problem, try this it should help you out:

Make a **odoo.conf** in the odoo directory.

```
[options]

admin_passwd = my_admin_password

# |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Port Options
# |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# |
# | Define the application port and longpolling ports.
# |

xmlrpc_port = 8069
```

Run the following command:

```
python3 odoo-bin -c odoo.conf --addons-path=addons -d test_new
```

Replace **test_new** with your own postgresql database. I previously made the DB using backend for some reason it didn't work with Odoo it seems so use PGAdmin as an alternative which fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar issue.
I wanna update my application, but I got an error, and then I checked my database found that the new field was not added.
Then I try to delete the admin_passwd in the odoo.conf and it worked!
The new database odoo15 was create successfully, but I still got this error.
[image]

Comment: now, I can login successfully by using Email:admin and Password:admin